# Absolute Value Property of Positive Linear Functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, trace

Let $A$ be a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra and $\rho$ a positive linear functional.

> Is it true that for all $a\in A$:
>
> $$|\rho(a)|\leq \rho(|a|),$$ where $|a|=\sqrt{a^\ast a}$?

This is not difficult to show when we restrict to $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$. Indeed if $a$ is self-adjoint, $a=a_+-a_-$ and $|a|=a_++a_-$ and so:

$$|\rho(a)|=|\rho(a_+)-\rho(a_i)|\leq |\rho(a_+)|+|\rho(a_-)|=\rho(a_++a_-)=\rho(|a|).$$

I also understand that I can write $a=u|a|$ for a unitary $u$ but I can't quite seem to be able to put the two sticks together. I know also that

$$|\rho(a)|^2\leq \rho(|a|^2).$$

I want to rewrite Hanno's argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286648/maximum-attaining-matrices-are-there-always-involutions/2287544#2287544) to a slightly different situation and if the above is indeed true then I have the result. There are probably different ways of doing it but this seems the obvious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality need not hold if the element $a$ is not self-adjoint. Here's a counterexample.

Suppose that $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$ and that 
$$a=\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Then $a$ has polar decomposition 
$$a=u|a|=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
If $\rho$ is the positive linear functional on $M_2(\mathbb C)$ given by
$$
\rho(x)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{3}{5} \\ \frac{4}{5}
\end{array}
\right),
$$
then 
$
\rho(|a|)=\frac{34}{25},
$
but $\rho(a)=\frac{36}{25}$.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Tom.